# Error from server (NotFound): error when creating rollout.yaml : the server could not find the requested resource (post rollouts.argoproj.io)

Tags: deployment, argocd, kubernetes-custom-resources, argo, argo-rollouts

Problem with creating argo rollouts CRD. When I try to apply CRD it gives me: error when creating "rollout.yaml": the server could not find the requested resource (post rollouts.argoproj.io)

This is my yaml:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Rollout
metadata:
  name: example-rollout
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: demo/template1:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: demo/template1-v1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
  strategy:
    canary:
      stableService: app1  
      steps:    # describes the strategy for sending traffic to the canary
      - setWeight: 30   # 30% of the traffic will go to the canary for 30 seconds
      - pause: {duration: 30}
      - setWeight: 60   # 60% of the traffic will go to the canary for 45 seconds
      - pause: {duration: 45}
      - setWeight: 100  # 100% of the traffic will go to the canary for 10 seconds
      - pause: {duration: 10}
```

Maybe the problem is because of image or labels

Comment: your terminology is off; when you try to apply the "CR" (not CRD), you get the error. that error is because the CRD has not been applied to the cluster. Once you apply the CRD, you can apply your CR!